# NeumannValue when differential equation does not use Laplacian

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method

## *The context:*

I am attempting to solve the differential equation d^2f(x,y)/dx^2=y^2*f(x,y) on the rectangle given by (x_min,x_max)=(0,1), (y_min,y_max)=(0,1) with the boundary conditions f(x_max,y)=1 and df/dx=-1 at (x_max,y). This can be done easily with a simple NDSolve call, e.g.

```
eqns = {D[f[x, y], x, x] == y^2*f[x, y], 
   f[xMax, y] == 1, (D[f[x, y], x] /. {x -> xMax}) == 1};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, f, {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}][[1]];
```

However, this is a toy model for a more complicated problem, which I need to solve on a predetermined coordinate grid `mesh`, e.g.,

```
xList = Range[xMin, xMax, 0.02];
yList = Range[yMin, yMax, 0.02];
coords = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, xList}, {y, yList}], 1];
nPointsX = Length[xList];
nPointsY = Length[yList];
meshElements = 
  Flatten[Table[
    QuadElement[{{(i - 1)*nPointsY + j, i*nPointsY + j, 
       i*nPointsY + j + 1, (i - 1)*nPointsY + j + 1}}], {i, 
     1, (nPointsX - 1)}, {j, 1, (nPointsY - 1)}], 1];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coords, 
   "MeshElements" -> meshElements];
```

(which creates a rectangular grid on the rectangular domain) as opposed to a grid that Mathematica generates internally. I attempt to do this by the following:

```
eqnsmesh = {D[f[x, y], x, x] == 
    y^2*f[x, y] + NeumannValue[1, x == xMax], 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == xMax]};
solmesh = NDSolve[eqnsmesh, f, Element[{x, y}, mesh]][[1]];
```

but this produces a different solution for `f[x,y]`. Indeed, I found that attempting to adapt my original PDE to use the `NeumannValue` feature:

```
eqns2 = {D[f[x, y], x, x] == 
    y^2*f[x, y] + NeumannValue[1, x == xMax], 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == xMax]};
sol2 = NDSolve[eqns2, f, {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}][[1]];
```

produces the same solution for `f[x,y]` as found with `eqnsmesh` and `solmesh` above.

## *The question:*

The Mathematica documentation for `NeumannValue`, while sparse, does indicate that this feature works on an understanding that the PDE uses the Laplacian, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#1529668360. My PDE, however, only uses two x derivatives, and therefore is not expressed in terms of the Laplacian. How can I format the `NeumannValue` arguments so that the solution produces the same function as `eqns` and `sol`, which don't require the `NeumannValue` feature to solve?

Comment: Please provide definition of `mesh` too.

Answer (score 1):

**modified**

The `NeumannValue` for your problem is well defined.

```
{xMin, xMax , yMin, yMax} = {0, 1, 0, 1}; (* you didn't provide these values*)
op = Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == y^2*f[x, y];
{state} =NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0 , DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == xMax] }, 
f, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[]];

NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE[state]
```

$\left\{\nabla _{\{x,y\}}\cdot \left(-\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).\nabla _{\{x,y\}}f(x,y)\right)-y^2 f(x,y)\right\}$

Coefficient of `Div .`  (see FEM documentation), here

```
-{{-1,0},{0,0}}.Grad[f]=={Derivative[1,0]f][x,y],0}
```

, multiplied by the unitnormal `{nx,ny}` of the boundary

```
{Derivative[1,0]f][x,y],0}.{nx,ny}==Derivative[1,0]f][x,y]nx
```

gives the `NeumannValue` which Mathematica FEM-solver allows.

As you might see for your problem NeumannValue only at boundaries `x==xMin` and `x==xMax` might be prescribed.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm still a bit confused on how NeumannValue would be implemented here. If I were to solve the PDE in the form you've given, I would use something like `op==0+NeumannValue[ ? ]`. What goes inside the NeumannValue function to specify the actual boundary conditions? From your answer, I see that in terms of the variables given in the documentation, `c` = {{-1,0},{0,0}}, `a`=-y^2, and alpha=beta=gamma=f=0. But the connection between `c` and the argument of the NeumannValue call that I need to implement is unclear, if such a connection exists.

Comment: @AndrewL From yanswer you get `-{{-1,0},{0,0}}.Grad[f]=={Derivative[1,0]f][x,y],0}`. This resulty has to be multiplied by the unit normal of the boundary to get the `NeumanValue`. See my modified answer!