# NDSolve FEM-Solver fails for simple PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

Trying to solve this pde (inspired by this question [NeumannValue when differential equation does not use Laplacian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/299621/neumannvalue-when-differential-equation-does-not-use-laplacian/299625?noredirect=1#comment738462_299625) )

```
pde = Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] ==y^2*f[x, y] + NeumannValue[1, x == 1 ]
bc = DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 1]  ;
F = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] ;
Plot[{Derivative[1, 0][F][1, y] }, {y, 0, 1},GridLines -> {None, {1}}, PlotRange -> {0, 1},PlotLabel ->"NeumannValue[1,x\[Equal]1] isn't fullfilled!" ]
```

[image]

In contrast to that solution my "handmade Galerkin method" gives a smooth result, which fullfills the Neumann condition quite well

[image]

(If of interest here my code [handmade Galerkin method](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ulrich.neumann/Published/galerkinUN.nb) )

I'm aware that `NeumanValue` in the first example is ignored because of `DirichletCondition` at the same boundary.

My question :

Is it possible to make FEM solution work for the case that Neumann and Dirichlet bcs are defined at the same place?

Thanks!

Comment: **Neumann and Dirichlet bcs are defined at the same place?** from [Neumann condition and Dirichlet condition at the same point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693859/neumann-condition-and-dirichlet-condition-at-the-same-point)  one of the answers says **applying Dirichlet boundary conditions will override your Neumann boundary conditions in the case of the finite element method**

Comment: @Nasser Thanks for your reply.  Galerkin method gets by without this restriction I think. First partial integration "processes"  the Neumann condition, then the unknowns of Dirichlet condition are inserted. This leads to the final set of equations.

Comment: I would like to see the code. Also, note that Dirichlet conditions apply at points while NeumannValues apply at edges (in 1D these are also points)

Comment: @user21 Thanks, I try to share the file but am unsure how to do it...

Comment: What do you mean with 'file' in your post you mentioned code. Could you not share that?

Comment: It is long code. Perhaps I can save the notebook in the Mathematica cloud?

Comment: As a side note, there is a [note](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html#533288859) about this not being possible currently, but who knows maybe you can - I just can not imagine how it's done right now.

Comment: @user21 Now my notebook is available, see link in my answer. Hope it's selfexplaining

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you very much for your code (+1). It looks like your code is not optimized yet.  It takes about 3 min on the mesh of 158 triangle elements only.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thank you for your reply. I only introduced Gaussian quadratur to make code faster. But it seems to work. Meanwhile I try(actual without success ;-) ) to use Mathametica `DiscretizePDE` functionality to make code run faster...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What boundary conditions you used at $y=0, 1$?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Only boundary conditions at `x==1` , see constraints  `RB1 = Map[fi[[#]] == 1 &, indexR1];`   in NMinimize

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It is not right. Probably we can use `pde` at the border `y==0` and `y==1`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't undersatnd "it is not right". Look at `NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == 
   y^2*f[x, y], {f[1, y] == 1, 
   Derivative[1, 0][f][1, y] == 1}}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` which gives the correct solution without additional bc using a  not-FEM solver.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann In a case of `NDSolve` with `Automatic` option we use `pde` at `y==0` and `y==1. These conditions equal to ``NeumanValue[0,y==0||y==1]` in a case of FEM. See my answer. Your solution has high error since you are not used boundary conditions at $y=0,1$ .

Comment: @AlexTrounev Which solution, from my last comment or from my answer, has large error ?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please compare your solution obtained with Galerkin method with `f[x,y]` from `NDSolve`  and with my solution `u1[x,y]`.

Answer (score 4):

To verifier solution computed with Galerkin method we can use the Euler wavelets collocation method from my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191476/poisson-equation-with-pure-neumann-boundary-conditions/191518#191518). We add boundary conditions at `y==0` and `y==1` in a form of homogenous Neumann condition or in a form of `pde`. First version

```
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t];
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/2^(k - 1) <= t <
       n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}];
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 4; With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
 nn = Length[Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]];
dx = 1/(nn); xl = Table[l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; zcol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1];
Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y;
int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
M = nn;

U1 = Array[a, {M, M}]; U2 = Array[b, {M, M}]; G1 = 
 Array[g1, {M}]; G2 = Array[g2, {M}]; G3 = Array[g3, {M}]; G4 = 
 Array[g4, {M}];

u1[x_, z_] := int2[x] . U1 . Psi[z] + x G1 . Psi[z] + G4 . Psi[z];
u2[x_, z_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int2[z] + z G2 . Psi[x] + G3 . Psi[x];
uz[x_, z_] := Psi[x] . U2 . int1[z] + G2 . Psi[x];
ux[x_, z_] := int1[x] . U1 . Psi[z] + G1 . Psi[z];
uxx[x_, z_] := Psi[x] . U1 . Psi[z];
uzz[x_, z_] := Psi[x] . U2 . Psi[z];
(*Equations and solution*)

eqn = Join[
  Flatten[Table[(uxx[xcol[[i]], zcol[[j]]] - 
      zcol[[j]]^2 u1[xcol[[i]], zcol[[j]]]), {i, M}, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    u1[xcol[[i]], zcol[[j]]] - u2[xcol[[i]], zcol[[j]]], {i, M}, {j, 
     M}]]]; bc = 
 Join[Flatten[Table[ux[1, zcol[[j]]] - 1 == 0, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[u1[1, zcol[[j]]] - 1 == 0, {j, 1, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[uz[xcol[[j]], 0] == 0, {j, M}]], 
  Flatten[Table[uz[xcol[[j]], 1] == 0, {j, M}]]]; var = 
 Join[Flatten[U1], Flatten[U2], G1, G2, G3, G4];

eq = Join[Table[eqn[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqn]}], 
    bc]; 

{v, m} = CoefficientArrays[eq, var];

sol1 = LinearSolve[m // N, -v];

(*Visualization*)
rul = Table[var[[i]] -> sol1[[i]], {i, Length[var]}];

Plot3D[Evaluate[u1[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]

Plot3D[Evaluate[u2[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 MeshStyle -> White]
```

[image: Figure1]

In second version we use `pde` as follows

```
eq0 = Join[Table[uxx[xcol[[i]], 0] == 0, {i, M}], 
   Table[uxx[xcol[[i]], 1] - u1[xcol[[i]], 1] == 0, {i, M}]];

eq1 = eq = 
  Join[Table[eqn[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqn]}], Take[bc, 2 M], 
   eq0]; sol2 = CoefficientArrays[eq1, var]

sol = LeastSquares[sol2[[2]] // N, -sol2[[1]]]
```

Solution `sol` is not differ from shown above `sol1`, which is already obvious.

**Update 1.** We can compare solution `u1[x,y]/.rul` and `u1[x,y]/.rul1` with

```
sol3 = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == 
    y^2*f[x, y], {f[1, y] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][f][1, y] == 1}}, 
  f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

We have

```
{Plot[Table[Abs[sol3[x, y] - u1[x, y] /. rul1], {x, 0, 1, .1}] // 
   Evaluate, {y, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"y", "\[Delta]f"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "Absolute error for `pde` at y=0,1"], 
 Plot[Table[Abs[sol3[x, y] - u1[x, y] /. rul], {x, 0, 1, .1}] // 
   Evaluate, {y, 0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"y", "\[Delta]f"}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "Absolute error for NeumannValue[0,y==0||y==1]"]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: This solution mifght be obtained with FEM-solver `eqnsFEM = {Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] ==  y^2*f[x, y] +  NeumannValue[1, x == xMax(*&&0\[LessEqual]y\[LessEqual]1*)] +  (1/2 E^-y (1 - E^(2 y) (-1 + y) + y)) NeumannValue[1, x == 0 ] , DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == xMax] };
solFEM = NDSolveValue[eqnsFEM, f, {x, xMin, xMax}, {y, yMin, yMax}] ;` too. As you can see there is no Neumanncondition at `y==0||y==1` included.

Comment: Interestingly the solution exactly fullfills NeumannValue and DirichletCondition. If we try to decrease the last NeumannCondition ` .1 (1/2 E^-y (1 - E^(2 y) (-1 + y) + y)) NeumannValue[1, x == 0 ]` this property is lost. Don't know why

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, you are right, FEM solution also computable, but homogeneous `NeumannValue[0, y==0]`  is `Automatic` option in this case, since this is `Automatic`  for any PDE without given boundary conditions.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that because for this special pde only  the derivative `Derivative[1,0][f][x,y]` at boundary `x=const` can be specified as NeumannValue.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You can check that  `Derivative[0,1][solFEM][x,0]=0`.

Comment: Thanks I checked it. But `Derivative[0, 1][solFEM][x, 1]!=0` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, from one side  implemented `NeumannValue[0, y==0]`, and from other side `pde`. It looks like this is optimal solution in L2 norm.

Comment: The solution also agrees with the analytical one `F = Values@DSolve[{Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == y^2*f[x, y], f[1, y] == 1,Derivative[1, 0][f][1, y] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 1 }, {y, 0, 1}]  [[1,1]]`, which only prescribes two boundary conditions.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you very much for these comments. Nevertheless, for numerical solution we need some boundary conditions at  $y=0, 1$ in a form of Dirichlet, Neumann or PDE.

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful discussion from me too. For numerical solution with Galerkin method I cannot agree. Have a look at my extended comment in the discussion with user21

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer but an extended comment. I think it would be good to simplify and speed up your code and make sure the FEM computations are correct. Following the [FEM Programming tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html.en) we get this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

pde = Derivative[2, 0][f][x, y] == 
   y^2*f[x, y] + NeumannValue[1, x == 1];
bc = DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 1];
F = data[{pde, bc}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
```

Using

```
NDSolveValue @@ F
```

gives what you had. This makes sure that we use the same input for NDSolveValus and for the system matrix extraction. Next we extract the system matrices:

```
{dPDE, dBC, vd, sd, md} = NDSolve`FEM`ProcessPDEEquations @@ F;
sm = dPDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
lv = dPDE["LoadVector"];
```

Next, we deploy the boundary conditions:

```
DeployBoundaryConditions[{lv, sm}, dBC];
```

Solve the linear equations:

```
result = LinearSolve[sm, lv];
```

And post process the solution:

```
NDSolve`SetSolutionDataComponent[sd, "DependentVariables", 
  Flatten[result]];
ProcessPDESolutions[md, sd]
```

Now, this solve the equation in exactly the same way like NDSolve would solve the PDE. What we can do next, is ignore the DirichletCondition. This will give a warning but we want to extract the load vector as if the DirichletCondition did not overwrite it:

```
F = data[{pde(*,bc*)}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
{dPDE, dBC, vd, sd, md} = NDSolve`FEM`ProcessPDEEquations @@ F;
smDummy = dPDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
lv = dPDE["LoadVector"];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{lv, smDummy}, dBC];
lv
```

Now, you have the load vector with the NeumannValue  deployed. In your notebook you transform the PDE into an optimization problem and I have some difficulty to understand what you are doing there. If you could show this minimization approach based on the stiffness matrix and the NeumannValue, that would be useful, for me to understand how you want to solve this.

Now, let's do another experiment. Now we ignore the DirichletBoundary condition altogether:

```
pde = Inactive[Div][{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}} . 
      Inactive[Grad][f[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - y^2*f[x, y] == 
   NeumannValue[1, x == 1];
(*bc=DirichletCondition[f[x,y]==1,x==1];*)
F = data[{pde(*,bc*)}, f, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

Proceed as before, now we get an expected message:

```
{dPDE, dBC, vd, sd, md} = NDSolve`FEM`ProcessPDEEquations @@ F;
sm = dPDE["StiffnessMatrix"];
lv = dPDE["LoadVector"];
```

[image]

```
DeployBoundaryConditions[{lv, sm}, dBC];
result = LinearSolve[sm, lv];
NDSolve`SetSolutionDataComponent[sd, "DependentVariables", 
  Take[Flatten[result], md["DegreesOfFreedom"]]];
{ifun} = ProcessPDESolutions[md, sd];
```

Now, we look at the result in the same way the OP has done:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Derivative[1, 0][ifun][1, y], 
   Derivative[1, 0][ifun][0, y]}], {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort. See my answer(extended comment)  which hopefully clarifies my approach.

Comment: Is `data`  in the definition of `F==data[...]` a  protected Mathematica variable?

Comment: No, why should it be? See update.

Comment: Because `data` is   undefined in the code , I thought.

Comment: Command `ProcessPDESolutions[md, sd]` in your code doesn't return an interpolation object on Mathematica v12.2.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point of it. This is a (hacky) way to store the same input to NDSolve and ProcessPDEEquations.

Comment: May have been introduced later.

Comment: Just saw the update. Unfortunately Mathematica v12.2 can't reproduce the last plot

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, try ElementMeshInteprolation[mesh, result] in place of the ProcessPDESolutions.

Comment: Thanks, still   [ I cannot reproduce your last plot:](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ulrich.neumann/Published/CannotReproduceLastPlot.nb)

Answer (score 1):

**modified**

Extended comment to answer @user21.

Meanwhile I could `DiscretizePDE` too. Here my code

```
{xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax} = {0, 1, 0, 1};
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
```

meshing

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{xMin, yMin}, {xMax, yMax}], 
"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001 , 
"MeshElementType" -> "TriangleElement", "MeshOrder" -> 1] ;
index = MeshCells[MeshRegion[mesh], 0][[All, 1]];

rand = mesh["BoundaryElements"][[All, 1]] // Flatten[#, 1] &;
indexR = Flatten[rand ] // DeleteDuplicates;
pi = mesh["Coordinates"]; (* alle Punkte *)
fi = Table[f[i], {i, 1, Length[pi]}];  (* Unbekannte DOFs *)

reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= yMax && x == xMax, {x, y}]; (* Randx\[Equal]xMax*) 
rand1 = Select[rand ,RegionMember[reg1, pi[[ #[[1]]]]] &&RegionMember[reg1, pi[[ #[[2]]]]] &];(* an diesem Rand gilt f[xMax,y]\[Equal]1*)
indexR1 = Flatten[rand1] // DeleteDuplicates;
```

discretization

```
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables","Space"} -> {{f}, {x, y}}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {mesh}];
cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, 
"DiffusionCoefficients" -> {{  {{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}}}, 
"ReactionCoefficients" -> {{-y^2} }];
bcdata = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd,sd, {{NeumannValue[1, x == 1]}}   ] 
mdata = InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd];

(*Discretization*)
dpde = DiscretizePDE[cdata, mdata, sd] ;
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["All"];

dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcdata, mdata, sd];
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness}, dbc];
```

solution

```
RB1 = Map[fi[[#]] == 1 &, indexR1];
mini = NMinimize[{(stiffness.fi - Flatten[load]) . (stiffness.fi-Flatten[load]), RB1}, fi];
solfun = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, fi /. mini[[2]]];

Plot3D[ solfun[x, y] , {x, y} \[Element] mesh, AxesLabel -> {x, y} ,
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}[[-1]], MeshFunctions -> (#3 &)]
```

[image]

```
Plot [ {Derivative[1, 0][solfun][1, y],Derivative[1, 0][solfun][0, y]} , {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**The result shows , the two Neumann-conditions and the DirichletCondition are fullfilled quite well.**

**It seems to be possible to get plausible results with Galerkin method, even if we take NeumannValue and Dirichletcondition at the same place of the boundary!**

**addendum**

With the last example (@user21 's extended comment) the minimization problem with matrices `smdummy` and `lv` follows after introducing
the dirichletcondition

```
RB1 = Map[fi[[#]] == 1 &, indexR1];(* all meshpoints `x==1`*)
mini = NMinimize[{(smdummy.fi + Flatten[lv]) . (smdummy.fi+    Flatten[lv]), RB1}, fi];
```

Comment: @user21 But it gives the same result found in galerkinUN.nb.

Comment: I'd say, because what you ask for can not be fulfilled.

Comment: @user21 But the last plot shows the Neumannconditions are "roughly" fullfiled!?

Comment: @user21 I am not yet convinced from your last comment, see my modified answer(extended comment) with refined mesh

Comment: You can use this: `bcdata2 = InitializeBoundaryConditions[vd, sd, {{DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 1]}}];
indexR1 = bcdata2["Stationary"][[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]]`
to compute the indexR1

Comment: @user21 Thanks, that makes it easier! Just one question: In my addendum (extended comment) I wondered about the sign of lv, are there any changes made compared to `load` before?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Have a look at the update. I have to stop here. I would want to work on other things.